# Correct syntax for Collectors.reducing

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, reducing

I have an **Order** class and a **LineItem** class like below:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
static class Order {
    long orderId;
    List<LineItem> lineItems;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
static class LineItem {
    String name;
    BigDecimal price;
}
```

and a list of orders, from which I want to get a map `Map<String,BigDecimal> totalByItem` where key is name of LineItem and value total price from all orders in the list. For this I want to use **Collectors.groupingBy** in combination with **Collectors.reducing** but struggling with the correct syntax. Can someone help?

```
List<Order> orders = List.of(new Order(1L, List.of(new LineItem("Item-A", BigDecimal.valueOf(1)),
                                                   new LineItem("Item-B", BigDecimal.valueOf(2)),
                                                   new LineItem("Item-C", BigDecimal.valueOf(3)))),
                             new Order(2L, List.of(new LineItem("Item-A", BigDecimal.valueOf(1)),
                                                   new LineItem("Item-D", BigDecimal.valueOf(4)),
                                                   new LineItem("Item-E", BigDecimal.valueOf(5)))),
                             new Order(3L, List.of(new LineItem("Item-B", BigDecimal.valueOf(2)),
                                                   new LineItem("Item-C", BigDecimal.valueOf(3)),
                                                   new LineItem("Item-D", BigDecimal.valueOf(4)))));
```

what to put where there are **???** now?

```
Map<String,BigDecimal> totalByItem =
         orders.stream()
                 .flatMap(order -> order.getLineItems().stream())
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LineItem::getName,
                          lineItem -> Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO,(a,b) -> ???)));
```

Comment: Why did you pass a lambda to the second parameter of `groupingBy`? That's supposed to be a `Collector`.

Comment: @Sweeper I have also tried without a lambda, `Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal::add)` but getting an error `Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds: BigDecimal and LineItem` I thought to extract the price, I need to use a lambda!?

Comment: You are reducing a bunch of `LineItem`s to a `BigDecimal`, so you should use [the 3-parameter overload](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing(U,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) takes a `Collector` as its second argument, so you should not pass the lambda `lineItem -> ...`, and instead pass the `Collector.reducing(...)` directly.

Also, since you are reducing a bunch of `LineItem`s to one `BigDecimal`, you should use the [three-parameter overload](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing(U,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) of `reducing`, with a `mapper`

```
public static <T, U> Collector<T,?,U> reducing(
    U identity,
    Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper,
    BinaryOperator<U> op)
```

The `mapper` is where you specify how a `LineItem` into a `BigDecimal`. You probably confused this with the second parameter of `groupingBy`.

So to summarise:

```
Map<String,BigDecimal> totalByItem =
    orders.stream()
        .flatMap(order -> order.getLineItems().stream())
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                LineItem::getName,
                Collectors.reducing(
                    BigDecimal.ZERO,
                    LineItem::getPrice, // <----
                    BigDecimal::add
                )
            )
        );
```

As Holger commented, the entire `groupingBy` collector can also be replaced with a `toMap` collector, without using `reducing` at all.

```
.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        LineItem::getName, // key of the map
        LineItem::getPrice, // value of the map
        BigDecimal::add // what to do with the values when the keys duplicate
    )
);
```

Comment: As (almost) always when combining `groupingBy` with `reducing`, just using `toMap` will be simpler and potentially more efficient: `Collectors.toMap(LineItem::getName, LineItem::getPrice, BigDecimal::add)`

Comment: @Holger Thank you! It always amazes me how one can reach a much better solution by just framing the question in a different way/thinking about it from a different perspective, which I admittedly often fail to do.

Answer (score 2):

You had it almost perfect.  You need to call mapping to pull the price from LineItem.  Then you can do the reducing operation as shown below.

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> totalByItem = orders.stream()
        .flatMap(order -> order.getLineItems().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LineItem::getName,
                Collectors.mapping(LineItem::getPrice,
                        Collectors.reducing(
                        BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));
```

Note that you could have done the reducing operation as follows:

```
Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a,b)->a.add(b)))));
```

With your current data, here is what prints
`totalByItem.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);`

```
Item-A=2
Item-E=5
Item-D=8
Item-C=6
Item-B=4
```